# is there an existing way to determine quantity on hand of a spree variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

for spree 3.0: i would like to be able to easily determine if a product has stock in a certain option value (in my case size, eg: 'medium'). i've been able to hack something together but this seems really clunky and i'd be really surprised if there wasn't a method that exists already to get this information. this is the code i've been able to come up with to create hashes of count on hand info for the various option values (size)

```
  count_hash_by_option_value_name = {}
  count_hash_by_option_value_id = {}
  stock_items = product.stock_items
  stock_items.each do |stock_item|
    if stock_item.variant.is_master
      puts "must be the master: #{stock_item.variant.option_values.inspect}"
    else
      count_hash_by_option_value_name[stock_item.variant.option_values.first.name] = stock_item.count_on_hand
      count_hash_by_option_value_id[stock_item.variant.option_values.first.id] = stock_item.count_on_hand
    end

  end
```

this gives me a hash of size name and count on hand values for this product

```
{"small"=>1, "medium"=>2, "large"=>0, "x-large"=>4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar which may meet your needs:

```
product = Spree::Product.find_by!(slug: 'ruby-on-rails-baseball-jersey')
Hash[product.variants.includes(option_values: :option_type).map { |v| [v.options_text, v.total_on_hand] }]
```

In the Spree sandbox this returns:

```
{
  "Size: S, Color: Red"=>10,
  "Size: S, Color: Blue"=>10,
  "Size: S, Color: Green"=>10,
  "Size: M, Color: Red"=>10,
  "Size: M, Color: Blue"=>10,
  "Size: M, Color: Green"=>10,
  "Size: L, Color: Red"=>10,
  "Size: L, Color: Blue"=>10,
  "Size: L, Color: Green"=>10,
  "Size: XL, Color: Green"=>10
}
```